# Chebyshev's inequality with expected value and variable swapped

Tags: probability

I have a distribution with $\mathbb{E}X=2$ and $\sigma^2=\frac{2}{3}$. I need to estimate $P(|\mathbb{E}X-X|\geq1)$. Is it the same as regular Chebyshev's inequality where under absolute value I have $X-\mathbb{E}X$? I know this might be obvious, but do absolute value works the same here and i can just swap expected value without consequences?

Comment: Since $|{-}y|=|y|$ for any real number $y$, we have $|\Bbb EX-X|=|{-}(X-\Bbb EX)|=|X-\Bbb EX|$.

Comment: @GregMartin thank you, that's what i thought.